Is it possible to use one Hive Metastore with different hive catalogs in Spark (Iceberg)?
What I have:

Holding's industries: fintech, telco, plants

Hive Metastore (with PostgreSQL) docker deployment available on thrift://hms-host:9083.
I've manually inserted additional 3 catalog records into CTLGS table (postgres):



CTLG_ID
NAME
DESC
LOCATION_URI




1
hive
Default catalog for Hive
file:/user/hive/warehouse


3
fintech
Catalog for Fintech
s3a://fintech


2
telco
Catalog for Telco
s3a://telco


4
plants
Catalog for Plants
s3a://plants



DBS table content:



DB_ID
DESC
DB_LOCATION_URI
NAME
OWNER_NAME
OWNER_TYPE
CTLG_NAME




1
Default Hive database
file:/user/hive/warehouse
default
public
ROLE
hive


6
Created by me Trino schema
s3a://fintech/digipays
digipays
carl.cox
USER
fintech


7
Created by me Trino schema
s3a://telco/worldonline
worldonline
carl.cox
USER
telco


8
Created by me Trino schema
s3a://plants/plastix
meters_bus
carl.cox
USER
plants


10
Created by collegaue from Spark somehow
s3a://corporate/sparkk.db
sparkk
john.digweed
USER
hive




Minio cluster available on https://my-minio-host:9000 endpoint with access and secret keys and 3 buckets: s3a://fintech s3a://telco s3a://plants



What I'm trying to achieve:
Write simple PySpark (3.5.1) code with correct configuration that will "see" and show list of available catalogs according to my catalogs in Hive Metastore (fintech, telco, plants)
My following simple PySpark code snippet returns only default and sparkk databases (they are both related to hive catalog), but supposed to return worldonline:
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

CATALOG_CLASS   = "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog"
CATALOG_TYPE    = "hive"
HMS_URI         = "thrift://hms-host:9083"
AWS_ENDPOINT    = "https://my-minio-host:9000"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY  = "123"
AWS_SECRET_KEY  = "12345678"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("IcebergHiveMetastoreIntegration") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.fintech",                     CATALOG_CLASS) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.telco",                       CATALOG_CLASS) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.plants",                      CATALOG_CLASS) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.fintech.type",                CATALOG_TYPE) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.telco.type",                  CATALOG_TYPE) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.plants.type",                 CATALOG_TYPE) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.fintech.uri",                 HMS_URI) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.telco.uri",                   HMS_URI) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.plants.uri",                  HMS_URI) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.fintech.default-namespace",   "fintech") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.telco.default-namespace",     "telco") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.plants.default-namespace",    "plants") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint",                     AWS_ENDPOINT) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key",                   AWS_ACCESS_KEY) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key",                   AWS_SECRET_KEY) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("USE telco")
spark.sql("SHOW CATALOGS").show()
spark.sql("SHOW NAMESPACES").show()
spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()

Output:
+-------------+
|      catalog|
+-------------+
|        telco|
|spark_catalog|
+-------------+

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|   sparkk|
+---------+

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|   sparkk|
+---------+


Note: in Trino with Iceberg connector everything works as expected - I added 3 Iceberg catalogs (fintech, telco, plants), specified the same Hive Metastore URI, and set hive.metastore.thrift.catalog-name=fintech etc. Just trying to replicate same behaviour in Spark.
